# Can I attach a unique ID to every copy of the .apk downloaded from my app's page on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

We are searching for a way for every copy of the app to have a unique id (used for registration etc.). Using device identifiers (MAC, phone number, IMEI) is not an option, as we need to provide this id from our side. Is there a way to do this? If not, another question would be if it's possible to know where the .apk was gotten from (for instance, can we tell a difference between the same .apk downloaded from Google Play and from Amazon Store)?

Comment: Have a look at this, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-how here you can pass a parameter which let u identify that the app was downloaded from gplay. Then you could generate the unique_id on a server and make a call on first start to the server and store it in your app, or just generate a unique number (timestamp in millis + random) at the start and save this app

Comment: @A.S. thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Please paste your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-how here you can pass a parameter which let u identify that the app was downloaded from gplay. Then you could generate the unique_id on a server and make a call on first start to the server and store it in your app, or just generate a unique number (timestamp in millis + random) at the start and save this app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can tell the difference between the same .apk downloaded from Google Play and from Amazon Store

Use [PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) to get the package name of application which installed the the application. The value is `com.android.vending` if the app was installed from Google Play.

e.g:

```
getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName()).equals("com.android.vending")
```